# Microsoft Teams – I know it is odd ;)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, microsoft-teams

I know it is odd to ask a question with regard a very,very cool Microsoft App ;) Anyway, let us be serious.
Problem is, that these days many schools, offices and companies are working with teams and I had many occassions the last year, where I was forced to use MS Teams.

So the question is:
Is there a way to install and use Teams within Ubuntu/Linux, with a RECENT version of teams.
I am working currently with the newest download from MS (deb file) but the version is
1.3.00.30857 (64-Bit)
where as far as I know 1.4 is out, with many new features (Grid-View, Breakout-Rooms, 3x3 up to 7x7 Grid View and so on).

So, does anyone have experience with a different setup?

Besides: I looked at winehq, but the emulated Teams App is rated as "Garbage". Anyone experience with regard to this?

Thanks!

Kubuntu 20.04 LTS
KDE Plasma 5.18.

Comment: That has been possible since 2019 already https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-is-now-available-on-linux/ba-p/1056267

Comment: https://snapcraft.io/teams

Answer (score 1):

- Add this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` to enable Microsoft Teams repository:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/ stable main
```

Remember to change `[arch=amd64]` to your CPU architecture if you're not using AMD64.

- Run `sudo apt update`
- Run `sudo apt install teams`

---

Regarding your note

> as far as I know 1.4 is out, with many new features

I can see two different packages: `teams` (v 1.3) and `teams-insiders` (v 1.4). Is it possible that this is what you meant?

```bsh
$ apt search teams

# ...

teams/stable 1.3.00.30857 amd64
  Microsoft Teams for Linux is your chat-centered workspace in Office 365.

teams-insiders/stable 1.4.00.4855 amd64
  Microsoft Teams for Linux is your chat-centered workspace in Office 365.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still this is only 1.3 version of teams, which is still an old version with a very restricted feature list compared to the windows versions...
teams-insider is a betatest version of teams. Gonna try it out thanks for the hint!

Comment: Okay i just tried teams-insider and it still has a very bad feature list. All the mentioned features (Breakoutrooms etc.) are not available also within this version. It is a mess and very sad, that MS is so ignorant with regard to Linux Zoom and all the others are not that ignorant. Also there are some bugs in teams-insider which i came across. All in all: If you want to seriously use MS Teams-Insider with the new features it is not possible on Linux these days. Reason is the bad Linux-Version of Teams. Does anyone know, if there will be a a new release of teams within the next decade?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux version is crippled (and will probably continue to be so for whatever reason) compared to the ones for Windows or OS X.

As a workaround, try the webpage-version of Teams instead: https://teams.microsoft.com.

Comment: Yes ... Better stop using Teams ;) After months and years of desperation ;)....